# Composer windows 10 install error, PHP7, Xampp 3.2, Mysql 5.6.2

Tags: php, composer-php

Trying to install composer on Windows/Xampp/PHP/Mysql.  Get the following error:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mysql.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_smtp.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_smtp.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_smtp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot open 'C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
```

**ADDRESSING THE ERRORS:**

1. In the PHP.ini file, it has:  **extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"** - this is correct.  then it says, "or the dll does not exist" - what dll is it looking for concerning the extension_dir, or is it referring to the items below, that they do not exist?  Don't know why this error is generated.
2. C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll - this does exist, so why is it telling me it cannot load it?
3. C:\xampp\php\ext\php_smtp.dll - this file does NOT exist.  Do I need it, is it somewhere else?  I am using phpMail and it is working, so this php_smtp.dll is for something else?
4. C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini - this file does NOT exist.  What is it, what should it be?
5. last error - what does it mean?

Comment: If you are using PHP/7 you cannot have a `php_mysql.dll` file at all, unless you've copied it from another location (which would explain the errors). Composer needs a  working PHP installation.

Comment: hmmm.... I originally instlaled Xampp/php5.6/mysql.   About 6 months ago, I upgraded from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 and left the rest, not wanting to install the new xampp/php/MariaDB combo because I wanted to keep Mysql, but seems like my PHP upgrade has gone slightly amiss, even though it seems to work fine for everything I am doing....?

Comment: SOLVED my problem by commenting/changing out those lines in the php.ini file:  track_errors = Off (from On), ;extension=php_mysql.dll, ;extension=php_smtp.dll, ;browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini".  Composer installed OK, but hopefully all my PHP functions will still work...!

Comment: I think you upgraded PHP but left the older configuration in place.